# Convert Subversion repository to Mercurial

Tags: svn, mercurial, migration, hgrc

I am trying to convert an SVN repository to Mercurial, but I'm having some troubles.  These are the steps I've taken:  (I am on Windows)

Turned on "convert" in the extensions

Opened a command window, and typed:

```
hg convert http://myversioncontrorepositoryhere
```

It says it's initializing the destination folder and then asks:

```
Enter username for Administration at http://myversioncontrorepositoryhere:
```

type my username then

```
 in Administration at http://myversioncontrorepositoryhere:
```

I assume this is my password, but it just loops back to

```
Enter username for Administration at http://myversioncontrorepositoryhere:
```

What am I doing wrong?  I'm very sure I'm typing in my username and password correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what may be going wrong, but I'd like to suggest a workaround (which is the only way I've personally used for this task!): first [svnsync](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/svnsync.txt) the svn project to make a local mirror, then `hg convert` that local mirror -- that's what O'Sullivan suggests in [his book](http://oreilly.com/opensource/excerpts/opensource-mercurial/migrating-to-mercurial.html) (this URL has, as "sample from the book", exactly the relevant appendix for importing projects from other VCSs to hg -- with special emphasis on svn!), though his suggestion is mostly inspired by considerations of speed I suspect that following it has also saved me authentication and authorization hassles, and I hope it could do the same for you!-)

Comment: I'm trying to do an svnsync, but i keep getting this error:  
svnsync: Repository has not been enabled to accept revision propchanges;
ask the administrator to create a pre-revprop-change hook

So I have enabled the pre-revprop-change hook, but it still happens.

Comment: Cancel that - the hook that's in there doesn't work under windows, it needs to contain "@exit 0"

Answer (score 3):

Try [hgsubversion](http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/wiki/Home) instead; it's a lot more robust.  I've had a lot of bizarre issues interacting with Subversion's CLI on Windows (mostly resolved by using CMD instead of another shell).

Comment: hgsubversion apparently can't cope with non-ASCII filenames, deciding to not interpret them as UTF-8 but Latin 1. Would you know any way around that?

Comment: File a bug? :) Seriously, it's all Python, it should be able to cope.

Answer (score 1):

I have had luck fixing the authentication problem by simply converting from a local checkout:

```
svn co http://myversioncontrorepositoryhere localrepo
hg convert localrepo
```

Comment: Good point! One downside is that you miss `trunk/` + `branches/` + `tags/` conversion....

Answer (score 1):

In my experience conversion of a real-word Subversion repository with bunch of projects and years of history is a little more involved. Mostly because in Subversion it's fine to have one huge repo for all the stuff. On the contrary Mercurial repositories are advised to be much more fine-grained.

I assume the following Subversion repository layout:

```
├── project1
│   ├── branches
│   ├── tags
│   └── trunk
│       ├── package1
│       └── package2
└── project2
```

Conversion should turn `package1` and `package2` into separate Mercurial repositories with their own history. In this answer I'm interested in single path, but conversion of tags and branches is also [possible](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#Options-1).

## Preparation

I usually do conversion on a remote server with fast connection. For Debian-family the following packages are required.

```
apt-get install mercurial subversion python-subversion
```

Then Convert extension should be enabled.

```
echo -e "[extensions]\nhgext.convert=" >> ~/.hgrc
```

On Windows make sure you've fulfilled [the prerequisites](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#Windows).

## Execution

Note, that if you try to do a conversion directly from a remote subversion repo it will likely take hours, so the following creates mirror of the project's path. Then each conversion is a matter of seconds to minutes.

```
cd /tmp
svnadmin create svn-mirror

# on Windows you may need to look at comments to accepted answer
echo '#!/bin/sh' > svn-mirror/hooks/pre-revprop-change
chmod +x svn-mirror/hooks/pre-revprop-change

svnsync init file:///tmp/svn-mirror svn://subversion.repo/project1
svnsync sync file:///tmp/svn-mirror

echo 'include project1/trunk/package1' > package1-map
echo 'rename project1/trunk/package1 .' >> package1-map    
hg convert --filemap=package1-map svn-mirror package1

echo 'include project1/trunk/package2' > package2-map
echo 'rename project1/trunk/package2 .' >> package2-map    
hg convert --filemap=package2-map svn-mirror package2
```

Then inside package directory you can run `hg serve -p 8080` and clone from `http://your.host:8080` with a mercurial client or repo manager like RhodeCode.